# Spring 3.1.1 and json getting error 406

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-3

I have written a simple rest based controller using @responseBody which I expect to return a JSON.
Somehow I am not able to get it work as expected.
when I run the url `"http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/amazon/rips"` ..it throws back below error

**HTTP Status 406 -JBWEB000126: The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request 'Accept' headers.**
can someone please lend a helping hand.

Mycontroller is below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/amazon")
public class JsonController {

@RequestMapping(value="/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody
Book getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

    Book book = new Book();
    book.setName(name);
    book.setAvailablity(false);

    return book;

}
```

Book class is below:

```
public class Book {

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isAvailablity() {
    return availablity;
}

public void setAvailablity(boolean availablity) {
    this.availablity = availablity;
}

private String name ;
private boolean availablity;
```

}

displatcher servlet is as below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.rips.controller" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Your request is comming in with an Accept header that doesn't include `application/json`.  Thus, you get the 406.  This is not a problem with the server-side code, but rather your client code.

Comment: the way I am testing is just calling http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/amazon/rips from my browser...is there anything wrong with this ?

Comment: Yes, it's sending the Accept as text/html.  You need to call it in a way that sets the Accept header to 'application/json'.  For instance you could use curl.  Or write a dummy HTML page that does an AJAX call that sets it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the help from @CodeChimp I realized that request that I was sending was not having proper accept headers.
I used Chromes "Advanced Rest client" and added headers with key ="accept" and value ="application/json",I was able to get proper response.

**update**
I found that     `<mvc:annotation-driven />` was not added in the dispatcher servlet which configures the support for HTTP message conversion with @RequestBody/@ResponseBody.Once I added this piece of info there was no need to use any advanced Rest client.